# Select element in Jquery selector by class name and convert it back to Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom, element

I don't understand why when i looking for how to get an element in list of element selected by class name like in traditional JS, I've always seen complicated answers .

```
document.getElementsByClassName('anyclass')[1]
```

so, i have found out myself that i cant do that (may be its the wrong approach)

```
$('.anyclass')[1]
```

but i get a DOM element! so logically i tried

```
$('.anyclass')[1][0]
```

and it doesnt work 'TypeError: $(...)[0][0] is undefined'
Anyone can explain why ? thank you!

Comment: `$('.anyclass')[1]` refers to DOM element, you don't need to do `[1][0]`

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but if you want to select a specific element in the collection contained in a jQuery object, use `eq()`, for example `$('.anyclass').eq(1)` would get the second `.anyclass` element

Comment: what im trying to do :
$('.anyclass')  get all elments with this class
$('.anyclass')[1] then pick out a DOM element
$('.anyclass')[1][0] finally convert it back to Jquery object 
by this way of thinking i've seen on an old post 

var elm = document.createElement("div");
var jelm = $(elm); //convert to jQuery Element
var htmlElm = jelm[0]; //convert to HTML Element"
but indeed i guess .eq() works fine but i wanted to understand why my logic didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/#eq-index)

```js
var secondElement = $('.anyClass').eq(1); //jQuery object
var domElement = secondElement[0]; //DOM element
console.log(secondElement, domElement)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='anyClass'>1</div>
<div class='anyClass'>2</div>
```

Comment: yes i've seen it ! but as i said i wanted to understand why my logic doesnt work :/ ?
why $('.anyclass')[0][0] didnt work ? because for me , it picked a DOM element and then i convert it to Jquery element, and i dont need .eq() ,right ?

Comment: @DoupDoup   `$('.anyclass')[1]` return DOM element  and its not an array so `$('.anyclass')[1][0]` return `undefined`. Your understanding _then i convert it to Jquery element_ is __wrong__.   To convert to jQuery you need `$($('.anyclass')[1])`

Answer (score 1):

```
var elm = document.createElement("div");
var jelm = $(elm); //convert to jQuery Element
var htmlElm = jelm[0]; //convert to HTML Element
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:first` pseudo-class is equivalent to `:eq( 0 )`. It could also be written as `:lt( 1 )`. While this matches only a single element, :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

here

```
$('.anyclass:first)
```

Quick example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $($(".t")[1]).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class=t>This 1.</p>
<p class=t>This 2.</p>
<p class=t>This 3.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

'

```
$('.anyclass')[0].attr("src");  you can use like this .
```

after your comment:
`$(".anyclass")[1]` is a DOM element not a jquery object. Simply wrap it as jquery `$($("td")[1]).width()`

Comment: yes that's it thank you ! but as i said i wanted to understand why my logic doesnt work :/ ?

Comment: `$('.anyclass')[1][0]` in this one you get error right?

Comment: yep ! 'TypeError: $(...)[0][0] is undefined'

Comment: what you are expecting to do with `$('.anyclass')[1][0]`

Comment: the same as $(".anyclass").eq(1)

Comment: you are saying that  to select 2nd of anyclass?

Comment: it is not that same `$('.anyclass')[1][0] ` as `$(".anyclass").eq(1) ` .thats why it gives error & it may escape from array & result in error try it in the snippet it will show the error

Comment: oh, because when u do this $('.anyclass')[1] it pick the second element of .anyclass but in DOM element so i was expecting that when you do  $('.anyclass')[1][0] to convert to qjery element (like karthik and some responses on the forum said 

var elm = document.createElement("div");
var jelm = $(elm); //convert to jQuery Element
var htmlElm = jelm[0]; //convert to HTML Element)  it supposed to works , right ?

Comment: well , i'll take it  , upvoted , thank you for your help !
edit : i can't upvote you , not enough reputation